# Sending Populated PDF Contracts via DocuSign API in PHP on AWS with Field Triggers Based on User Selections - Struggling with PHP SDK Installation

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, pdf, docusignapi, docusign-sdk

Need guidance to send pre-populated PDF contracts via DocuSign API on AWS with field triggers based on user selection. Struggling with PHP SDK installation.

How can I use the DocuSign API or an intermediary program to send .pdf contracts, which are automatically populated with data from a web-based application in a database on an AWS server with Linux and PHP 8.1, while only triggering initialing on selected fields? I have reviewed the DocuSign documentation, but I am still unclear on the best approach for my situation. Additionally, I am having trouble installing the PHP SDK.

Since I cannot use WebMerge/FormStack due to certain fields requiring signature triggers only if there is a value in other fields, I am seeking suggestions on the simplest and most straightforward way to achieve this goal. Any help with the PHP SDK installation or guidance on the best approach to my problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Tried DocuSign docs for PHP SDK, unable to install it. Seeking guidance for field triggers on pre-populated PDF contracts sent via API.

Answer (score 0):

> Additionally, I am having trouble installing the PHP SDK.
> What trouble? you get an error? can you elaborate? It's not clear, so hard to help.

However, I suggest you start by using DocuSign Quickstart - https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/ and pick PHP.

You need to decide what auth you will use (JWT or ACG) and this quickstart wizard will set it all for you and generate code that should just run for you.

the code will do just that - send a PDF for signature. You can later modify it to suit your needs